# Does Spring Boot 3.0 check for references to JDK internal API in its components?

Tags: spring-boot, java-17

I'm currently working the investigation of Spring Boot 3.0 and I have a question regarding its handling of JDK internal API references in component vendors.

Specifically, the sprinboot 3.0 required jdk 17+ and which jdk version need add "--add-opens or --add-exports" param when the application or libraries visit the jdk internal API. So,I'm wondering if Spring Boot 3.0 checks for references to the JDK internal API (i.e., whether --add-opens is needed) in components.

If it doesn't perform this check, would an exception occur when a user tries to use a component that references the JDK internal API?

If it does perform this check, could someone explain how this is implemented?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

The solution to check the JDK internal API usage in the components.

Comment: Try and you will see. But to answer it there is no check.